# Can you Aggregate LocalDateTime in MongoDb with Morphia

Tags: mongodb, java-8, morphia

I am using Morphia to access my mongoDB.

One of my collections has a lastUpdatedTimestamp declared as Java8 LocalDateTime.

I am using this java code:-

```
Iterator<CountResult> iterator = datastore.createAggregation(MyClass.class).group(Arrays.asList(Group.grouping("$year", "timestamp")), Group.grouping("count", new Accumulator("$sum", 1))).aggregate(CountResult.class);
```

I wish to aggregate my data based on $year $month $day $hour however just try either $hour or $year I get this exception

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16006: 'can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date", "code" : 16006 }
```

Is it possible to aggregate Java8 LocalDateTime's with morphia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention of how your LocalDateTime is stored at the mongodb document structure.

```
        "lastUpdatedTimestamp": {
        "date": {
            "year": NumberInt("2016"),
            "month": NumberInt("11"),
            "day": NumberInt("3")
        },
        "time": {
            "hour": NumberInt("4"),
            "minute": NumberInt("55"),
            "second": NumberInt("43"),
            "nano": NumberInt("0")
        }
    }
```

Probably the field lastUpdatedTimestamp is the object with two objects inside: date and time, each has corresponding integers.

In this case you should query and aggregate such field, as example below

```
db.MyClass.aggregate(
{"$group" : { "_id": "$lastUpdatedTimestamp.date.day", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
{"$match": {"count" : {"$gt": 1} } })
```

it's not morphia, but you've get the idea.